# Flask + Celery task duplications on 3rd party notifications

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

I have a flask app which sends emails/SMSs to users at a specific time using the ETA/Countdown celery functions with Redis as a broker, The issue is the emails & SMS tasks duplicate randomly - sometimes users get 10 emails/SMSs sometimes users get 20+ for these tasks and the task is only supposed to run once off. The data flow:

1. Initial function schedule_event_main calls the ETA tasks with the notifications

```
   date_event = datetime.combine(day, time.max)
   schedule_ratings_email.apply_async([str(event[0])], eta=date_event)
   schedule_ratings_sms.apply_async([str(event[0])], eta=date_event)
```

2. Inside function schedule_ratings_email & schedule_ratings_sms task is the .delay task function which creates the individual celery tasks to send out the emails + SMSs to the various guests for an event.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def schedule_ratings_email(self,event_id):
    """ Fetch feed of URLs to crawl and queue  up a task to grab and process
    each url. """
    try:
        url = SITE_URL + 'user/dashboard'
        guests = db.session.query(EventGuest).filter(EventGuest.event_id == int(event_id)).all()
        event_details = db.session.query(Event).filter(Event.id == event_id).first()
        if guests:
            if event_details.status == "archived":
                for guest in guests:
                    schedule_individual_ratings_emails.delay(guest.user.first_name, guest.event.host.first_name, guest.user.email,url)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("Error processing ratings email for %s" % event_id, exc_info=e)
        # self.retry()
```

3. This is the final .delay individual task for sending the notifications:

```
@app.task()
def schedule_individual_ratings_emails(guest_name, host, guest, url):
    try:
        email_rating(guest_name, host, guest, url)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("Error processing ratings email for %s", exc_info=e)
```

I've tried multiple SO answers and tweaked a lot of variables including celery settings however the notifications are still duplicating. It's only the ETA/Countdown tasks and ONLY with 3rd party servers as I have certain ETA tasks which have DB data writing and those tasks don't have any issues.

This is both an issue on local and heroku (production). Current tech stack:
Flask==1.0.2
celery==4.1.0
Redis 4.0.9
Celery startup: worker: celery worker --app openseat.tasks --beat --concurrency 1 --loglevel info
Celery config details:

```
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Africa/Johannesburg'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```